# How to start application even though Connecting to IBM MQ with Spring Boot and JMS fails

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, ibm-mq

I am trying to connect to IBM MQ from my spring boot application.

Whenever the MQ goes down and at the same time if I start the server, the spring boot application is failing to start up.

Here is the exception I encounter.

```
 Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jmsTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'connectionFactory' defined in class path resource
```

Here are my two primary targets:

1. I want to make sure that my application should start up even though the IBM MQ server is down. How can I achieve?
2. Is there a way to keep checking for MQ server status and initialize the connection factory dynamically given that application started and running.

Exception Stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'MQGateway' defined in file [C:\GP-Source-Code\gp-api-gateway\target\classes\com\girishk\gp\api\tierc\MQConnect\config\mq\MQGateway.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jmsTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/girishk/gp/api/tierc/MQConnect/config/mq/MQConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jmsTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'connectionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'connectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [mq.local.tax.qcf] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [mq.local.tax.qcf].
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:754)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
    at com.girishk.gp.api.tierc.MQConnect.MQConnectApplication.main(MQConnectApplication.java:13)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jmsTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/girishk/gp/api/tierc/MQConnect/config/mq/MQConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jmsTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'connectionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'connectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [mq.local.tax.qcf] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [mq.local.tax.qcf].
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1022)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1131)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1059)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'connectionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'connectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [mq.local.tax.qcf] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [mq.local.tax.qcf].
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1022)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1131)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1059)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'connectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [mq.local.tax.qcf] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [mq.local.tax.qcf].
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [mq.local.tax.qcf] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [mq.local.tax.qcf].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:816)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:173)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:163)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:155)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:179)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate.lookup(JndiLocatorDelegate.java:63)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration.connectionFactory(JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration.java:67)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$68df3ef5.CGLIB$connectionFactory$0(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$68df3ef5$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3ee17e50.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$68df3ef5.connectionFactory(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 47 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Please, share more StackTrace. It must not connect during bean initialization.

Comment: I just updated the question with additional stack trace.

Comment: `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [mq.local.tax.qcf] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [mq.local.tax.qcf].` means that there is no an appropriate JNDI value. That fully doesn't mean that MQ Broker is dead. You just have misconfiguration.

Comment: If I supply correct JNDI value does it require to have the MQ Broker is up and running all the time? Or for creating connection is the a valid JNDI alone enough?

Comment: No, only when you perform active operation (send or receive), then it performs connect

Comment: Sure.. Thanks for the comment. Let me do few more research around this.